# I cant assign my GameObject variable. Please assist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to assign ScriptManager to ObjectManager, and used the line :

```
ObjectManager = GameObject.Find("ScriptManager");
```

I have checked multiple times to make sure "ScriptManager" is spelt correct, I've even tried copy pasting the name straight from Unity.

I receive this error when running:

> "UnassignedReferenceException: The variable ObjectManager of Mining
> has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the ObjectManager
> variable of the Mining script in the inspector.
> UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent[T] () (at
> <3be1a7ff939c43f181c0a10b5a0189ac>:0) Mining.Sell () (at
> Assets/Mining.cs:49)"

I sadly can't assign the variable straight from the inspector, because the object with the code attached is loaded using a Prefab.

here is the full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Mining : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject ObjectManager;
public Text WorkerCountText;
public float MiningSpeed;

public float WorkersInMine;
public float MiningMultiplyer;

public Collider2D collider;
public GameObject DropDown;


private float WorkerCount;

private float MineWorth;
private float Cash;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    ObjectManager = GameObject.Find("ScriptManager");
    collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    DropDown.SetActive(false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Cash = ObjectManager.GetComponent<GenerateItems>().Money;
    WorkerCount = ObjectManager.GetComponent<GenerateItems>().Workers;
    MineWorth = ObjectManager.GetComponent<GenerateItems>().MineCost;
    
    WorkerCountText.text = "Workers:" + WorkerCount;  
   
}

public void Sell()
{
    ObjectManager.GetComponent<GenerateItems>().Money = Cash + MineWorth;
    Object.Destroy (this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered how to fix it!

For anyone wondering, the object this is attacked to is a prefab. And is only loaded once the player purchases the item. Meaning it is not loaded when Start() is executed. Moving the line into Sell() , Add() , and remove assigns it when the buttons are clicked. This fixed the error. Thank you to everyone who tried to help, I am now also using FindGameOBjectWithTag instead of Find to make sure it always works

Answer (score 0):

I would change the way how you assign the ScriptManager to ObjectManager. The function Find() is not very reliable and in case if anything changes in hierarchy or in the name of the GameObject, the function will not find the desired GameObject.

There are multiple ways how you can assign the GameObject to the ObjectManager, including more reliable function FindObjectOfType(), or simply creating variable:

public GameObject objectManager;

and dragging your ObjectManager from the hierarchy into the inspector in the ScriptManager GameObject.

Note: If you want to use any function of the ObjectManager you would need to get that component in the Start function of the ScriptManager.

Comment: Like I said. I cannot assign the ObjectManager into the inspector as the Object with this script is a prefab and does not exist in the game until the user "purchases" one. I will try using FindObjectOfType(). Gimmi a sec

Answer (score 0):

Try using Object.FindObjectOfType

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html

Comment: thank you for the response. I have just tried FindObjectOfType but it didnt work, so i tried FindGameObjectWithTag but it is still not finding it? The tags are identical for waht it is named and what i am searching for in the () . What could be causing this?